# Can't stop vertical scroll while horizontal scrolling slider (No framework)

Tags: javascript, css

I had a problem when I tried to implement 2 horizontal scrolling sliders (probably a third one) into the same webpage. The vertical scrolling continues when I scroll the slider. I can even not see all the photos of each of these sliders.

In the beginning, I tried to build just one horizontal scrolling slider with Vanilla JS, like this, it worked perfectly:

```
const images = [...document.querySelectorAll('img')];
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
let sliderWidth;
let imageWidth;
let current = 0;
let target = 0;
const ease = .05;


function lerp(start, end, t) {
    return start * (1 - t) + end * t;
}

function init() {
    sliderWidth = slider.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    imageWidth = sliderWidth / images.length;
    document.body.style.height = `${sliderWidth - (window.innerWidth - window.innerHeight)}px`;
}


function animate() {
    current = parseFloat(lerp(current, target, ease)).toFixed(2);
    target = window.scrollY;
    //setTransform(slider, `translateX(-${current}px)`);
    slider.style.transform = `translate3d(${-current}px, 0, 0)`
    //requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

init();
animate();
```

But when I added the 2nd slider under the 1st one, this code didn't work anymore. I did some research and tried another way to do that:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < sliderSections.length; i++) {
        animate(sliderSections[i]);
    }
})

function animate(section) {
    const offsetTop = section.parentElement.offsetTop;
    console.log(offsetTop);
    const scrollSection = section.querySelector('.slider-inner');
    console.log(scrollSection);
    console.log(window.scrollY);
    console.log(window.innerHeight);
    let percentage = ((window.scrollY - offsetTop) / window.innerHeight) * 100;
    percentage = percentage < -100 ? 0 : percentage > 400 ? 400 : percentage;
    console.log(percentage);
    scrollSection.style.transform = `translate3d(${-(percentage)}vw, 0, 0)` 
}
```

But the vertical scrolling continues when I scroll the slider. I can even not see all the photos of each of these sliders, it jumped already to the 2nd one. Maybe there is a problem with the 'percentage' variable, but I couldn't find the solution.

Could you please help me to solve this problem? Or maybe there is a way to make it using the 1st method that I've used to create a horizontal scrolling slider?
**Thank you very much.**

Here are the HTML and CSS code

HTML:

```
<section class="main">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slider-inner">
                    <div class="item hoverable">
                        <img src="images/osaka/1.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item hoverable">
                        <img src="images/osaka/2.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item hoverable">
                        <img src="images/osaka/3.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item hoverable">
                        <img src="images/osaka/4.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item hoverable">
                        <img src="images/osaka/5.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item hoverable">
                        <img src="images/osaka/6.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>

        <section class="main main2">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slider-inner">
                    <div class="item hoverable">
                        <img src="images/osaka/1.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item hoverable">
                        <img src="images/osaka/2.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item hoverable">
                        <img src="images/osaka/3.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item hoverable">
                        <img src="images/osaka/4.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item hoverable">
                        <img src="images/osaka/5.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item hoverable">
                        <img src="images/osaka/6.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11.1%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5000px;
  height: 100%;
  will-change: transform;
}

.slider-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 77%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*filter: grayscale(100%);*/
  /*visibility: hidden;*/
  /*opacity: 0;*/
}
```